# What does it mean if something is equal to -1?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain to me what it means?

Example:

```java
for(char ch : (a+b).toCharArray()){
  if(a.indexOf(ch) == -1 || b.indexOf(ch) == -1){
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to understand the meaning of `-1`.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))? What is unclear about that? Your first reflex should be to consult the documentation, not ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

a.indexOf(ch) == -1:
It means that the character ch is not found in string a
Extended explanation:
indexOf() : This method returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1, if the character does not occur.

Answer (score -1):

-1 if it never occurs.

learn more about the method here -
https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_indexof.asp